# Django Query - Select Where

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I have a `Client`, `Users` and `ClientUsersAssignment` table. Clients are assigned to one more more users.

I need to retrieve the list of clients the given user has access to. How do I construct my filter?

I have included the SQL equivalent in the snippet below.

```
Client.objects.filter ( 
    # SQL Equivalent Statement
    WHERE request.user.id IN (SELECT user FROM ClientStaffAssignment WHERE clientid = client.id)
)
```

And the django models for completeness:

```
class User(models.Model):

  id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  username        = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  password        = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Client(models.Model):

  id             = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  first_name     = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_name      = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class ClientStaffAssignment(models.Model):

  id             = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  client         = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  user           = models.ForeignKey (User, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: your `Client` model has no relation to `ClientStaffAssignment` and `User` model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the key here is adding the `ManyToManyField` on the `Client` model and ensuring the foreign keys are set on the intermediary (`ClientStaffAssignment`) model. With that in place the filter is very simple. [Reference on intermediary many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

Queryset

```
Client.objects.filter( assigned_staff=request.user )
```

Modified models

```
class User(models.Model):

  id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  username        = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  password        = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)


class Client(models.Model):

  id             = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  first_name     = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_name      = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
  assigned_staff = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ClientStaffAssignment')


class ClientStaffAssignment(models.Model):

  id             = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  client         = models.ForeignKey(Client, blank=True, null=True)
  user           = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Client` and `User` have a many-to-many relationship in this case, so you should define you `Client` and `User` with a `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    clients = models.ManyToManyField(Client)
```

So that you can easily obtain a list of clients a given user is assigned to:

```
for user in User.clients.all():
    print(user)
```

Please read [Many-to-many relationships documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships).

On a side note, `id` field is automatically generated for every model, so you don't have to define it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I have answered with the solution.